# After upgrade to 23.04, Alienware Alpha still doesn't detect USB speakers

Tags: sound, usb, speakers

Previously on 19.04, my Alienware Alpha has a USB powered that was never detected. It only shows the audiojack on the motherboard or the monitor built-in speakers. I upgraded to 23.04 and the USB speakers still aren't detected. I see that they're powered on and I've tried different USB ports.

Any suggestions why they're not being detected?

Comment: Warning notices of Ubuntu 23.04's *end of life* have already gone out (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/12/15/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reaches-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/) so if you just *release-upgraded* to that release, please start planning your *release-upgrade*. I'd plan your upgrade before worrying about speakers.

Comment: Edit your question to answer: Are the speakers shown in the output of `lsusb` ?